# How to prepend a Python 'deque' object as part of a list comprehension

Tags: python, collections, jsonschema

I am using `jsonschema` to validate a JSON document, and if there are any errors I need to capture them, including the path to the errors in the document. To ensure that path is never empty (i.e. if a required key at the root of the document is missing), I wish to prepend the path to errors with **root**.

```py
v = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(schema_dict)
errors = sorted(v.iter_errors(payload_dict), key=lambda e: e.path)

if len(errors) > 0:
    paths = ['.'.join(deque(('root')) + e.absolute_path) for e in errors]
    messages = [f'{p}: {e.message}' for e, p in zip(errors, paths)]
    raise InvalidPayloadException(messages) from None
```

For example, if the properties `obj.key1` and `obj.key2` were required and the following JSON document was tested.

```json
{
    "obj": {
       "keyx": "value"
    }
}
```

**What I'd expect `messages` to contain** is the following list.

```py
["root.obj: 'key1' is a required property", "root.obj: 'key2' is a required property"]
```

**What `messages` actually contains** is **root** as four separate elements.

```py
["r.o.o.t.obj: 'key1' is a required property", "r.o.o.t.obj: 'key2' is a required property"]
```

How can I amend my code so that messages contains the expected text? Preferably, I'd like to keep a list comprehension as they tend to be quite readable and don't take up much real estate, but I'm open to changing that if required.

---

I have also seen that the documentation for `deque` mentions [`appendleft()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.appendleft), but using that causes an error.

```py
paths = ['.'.join(e.absolute_path.appendleft('root')) for e in errors]
```

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Not my choice... that's what `jsonschema` gives me for `absolute_path`.

Comment: Ah, I see now, I suspect you meant `deque(('root',))` instead of `deque(('root'))`, notice the comma

Comment: Because `absolute_path` is a `deque`, and I am trying to prepend that `deque` with my own item (`root`). If that is the wrong choice, please offer a suggestion.

Comment: The comma does make all the difference, and now I have `root.obj` as expected. Thanks for that.

Comment: So, using an analogy with lists, `list("root") -> ["r", "o", "o", "t"]` and `list(("root",)) -> ["root"]`

Comment: Yes, @juanpa.arrivillaga comma makes it a tuple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is you were passing a single string object to the `dequeue` constructor, which works like other sequence-like constructors in Python, it accepts an arbitrary iterable and constructs a dequeue by iterating over the iterable.

But I noticed you used an extra set of parentheses, so I think you meant to pass a singleton tuple. You actually need a comma for that, so what you wanted was:

```
paths = ['.'.join(deque(('root',)) + e.absolute_path) for e in errors]
```

Notice the comma. `deque(('root'))` -> `deque(('root',))`

I think it would be cleaner, though, to just do:

```
paths = ['.'.join(['root', *e.absolute_path]) for e in errors]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of why I was seeing the issue, and your final suggestion works and is certainly cleaner.